# Swift - Dictionary from 2 filtered arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
idsArr = [ ["id": "12345"], ["id": "27891"],["id": "98654"] ]
idsNameIntvalueArr = [["id": "22913", "name" : "Peter Parker", "value": 15], ["id": "12345", "name" : "Donald Duck", "value": 6],  ["id": "98654", "name" : "Mickey Mouse", "value": 9], ["id": "112233", "name" : "Lion King", "value": 9]]
```

I'm new in Swift, please give me advice, what is the best practice to compare this 2 arrays by id, if id matches, how to get the array with dictionaries inside, in result like this:

```
resultArr = [["Donald Duck": 6],["Mickey Mouse": 9]]
```

or even better just a dictionary, if it possible:

```
resultdict = ["Donald Duck": 6, "Mickey Mouse": 9]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your second example ( resultdict = [Donald Duck: 6, Donald Duck: 6] ) is invalid since a dictionary can not hold two identical keys.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, i mean:
`resultdict = ["Donald Duck": 6, "Mickey Mouse": 9]`
Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @Rurom Plz check out the answer and let me know if you have any confusion. !!

Comment: @Salman Ghumsani pls check my comment below your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 3.x

```
let idsArr = [ ["id": "12345"], ["id": "27891"],["id": "98654"] ]
let idsNameIntvalueArr = [["id": "22913", "name" : "Peter Parker", "value": 15], ["id": "12345", "name" : "Donald Duck", "value": 6],  ["id": "98654", "name" : "Mickey Mouse", "value": 9], ["id": "112233", "name" : "Lion King", "value": 9]]

var result = [String:Int]()

idsNameIntvalueArr.forEach({ name in
  idsArr.forEach({
    if name["id"] as? String == $0["id"] { result[name["name"] as! String ] = name["value"] as? Int }
  })
})
print(result)
```

Will return:

```
["Mickey Mouse": 9, "Donald Duck": 6]
```

Comment: @Rurom Could you please mark this answer as correct?